# Argue that the iterated integral of a continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $f : [a, b] \times [c, d] \to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. Let
$$G(y)= \int_a^b f(x, y) \, dx$$
$$H(x)= \int_a^b f(x, y) \, dy$$

Prove that $G$  is continuous on $[c, d]$ and $H$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

So I know that the function will be uniformly continuous on the interval but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: If $y_n \rightarrow y$, can you show
$$\lim_n \int_a^b f(x,y_n) dx =  \int_a^b \lim_n f(x,y_n) dx ?$$

Comment: No? i'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, we prove $G$ is continuous. The other is analogous.

Fix $y_0>0$. Now, $G(y_0)=\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y).$

Given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $|f(p)-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$ whenever $p,q$ are in a square of side $\delta$ (this is uniform continuity). That is, $f(q)-\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}<f(p)< f(q)+\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$.  Clearly we can cover the strip $[a,b] \times (y_0-\delta,y_0+\delta)$ by finitely many such squares (you can argue by compacity, but since the side is constant, a simple counting will do).

Now, this implies that, if $y \in (y_0-\delta, y_0+\delta)$, we have
$$\big(\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y_0)\big)-\epsilon=\big(\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y_0)-\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\big)\leq \int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y) \leq \big(\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y_0)+\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\big)=\big(\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y_0)\big)+ \epsilon.$$

Hence,
$$\vert\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot,y) -\int\limits_a^bf(\cdot, y_0)\vert <\epsilon$$
$$\therefore \vert G(y)-G(y_0) \vert <\epsilon. $$